# After building the apk using react expo camera is not opening and selected files don't get uploaded and the location isn't getting accessed

Tags: css, react-native, permissions, expo, apk

After building the apk using react expo camera is not opening and selected files don't get uploaded and the location isn't getting accessed

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "kuku",
    "slug": "kuku",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ff0000"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "permissions": [
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
      ],
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ff0000"
      },
      "package": "com.pawarshekhar708.kuku"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "4ae338dd-b785-45db-92a8-492c6f0928de"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried giving permissions but still it isn't opening. The app works perfectly before building the apk.
i dont know why this is happening as I have given all the permissions

Comment: In this happening in IOS or Android ?

Comment: This happening in android